# How to supply unit_count_type and unit_count Amazon product data feed?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I supplied value of unit of Measure and Unit count in _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ feed.

```
XmlElement unitOfMeasure = xmlDocument.CreateElement("unitOfMeasure");
unitOfMeasure.InnerText = "Count";
Product.AppendChild(unitOfMeasure);

 XmlElement UnitCount = xmlDocument.CreateElement("UnitCount");
 UnitCount.InnerText = "1";
 Product.AppendChild(UnitCount);
```

My xml feed looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>book1568388578</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ASIN</Type>
        <Value>1568388578</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
      <unitOfMeasure>count</unitOfMeasure>
      <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Relapse Prevention Long-term Workbook</Title>
        <Brand> </Brand>
        <Description> </Description>
        <BulletPoint> </BulletPoint>
        <BulletPoint> </BulletPoint>
        <MSRP currency="USD">70.74</MSRP>
        <Manufacturer>Hazelden Foundation,U.S.</Manufacturer>
        <ItemType>books</ItemType>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Health>
          <ProductType>
            <HealthMisc>
              <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
              <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
            </HealthMisc>
          </ProductType>
        </Health>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>

</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I am getting following error in feed result.

> XML Parsing Error at Line 19, Column 22: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'unitOfMeasure'. One of '{LaunchDate, DiscontinueDate, ReleaseDate, ExternalProductUrl, Condition, Rebate, ItemPackageQuantity, NumberOfItems, LiquidVolume, DescriptionData, DiscoveryData, ProductData, ShippedByFreight, EnhancedImageURL, Amazon-Vendor-Only, Amazon-Only, RegisteredParameter, NationalStockNumber, UnspscCode, UVPListPrice}' is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. You need to provide this feed of unit count in HealthMisc
Correct xml..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>book1568388578</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ASIN</Type>
        <Value>1568388578</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Relapse Prevention Long-term Workbook</Title>
        <Brand> </Brand>
        <Description> </Description>
        <BulletPoint> </BulletPoint>
        <BulletPoint> </BulletPoint>
        <MSRP currency="USD">70.74</MSRP>
        <Manufacturer>Hazelden Foundation,U.S.</Manufacturer>
        <ItemType>books</ItemType>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Health>
          <ProductType>
            <HealthMisc>
              <UnitCount unitOfMeasure="Count">1</UnitCount>
              <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
              <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
            </HealthMisc>
          </ProductType>
        </Health>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```